# Freeform - Errors - Can't Create New Fields or Submit Forms

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I upgraded to EE v2.7 and am running into some issues with FreeForm. I am running the latest version of FreeForm v4.0.12

1. I can't add new fields in the CMS. Whenever I submit a new field form I am taken to the CMS home screen and the field isn't added.
2. I can't submit forms on the front-end website. I receive the error message 'You are not authorized to perform this action - Reason: Secure Forms Timeout'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EE 2.7 shipped with changes that break existing code, and so most or all of the Solspace add-ons are currently incompatible with EE 2.7.

Solspace posted that they were working on updates ["over the course of the next two weeks"](http://www.solspace.com/blog/entry/compatibility_with_ee_2.7.0/). That was two weeks ago, but I suspect we'll see new releases from Solspace, soon.

Like you, I'm stuck right now with things not working... and clients waiting...

Comment: Thanks for the link, I should have done a little more research.